# Button click event hiding the dynamically created panel on codebehind click event

Tags: asp.net, submit

I am designing an asp.net webform that  reads an xml file and creates dynamic table with labels and textboxes and finally added to a panel .
 On button save click event -
 codebehind -I am validating  the input text box values if any one is null I have to stay in the same page. but the page is getting refreshed hiding my panel ,all controls and just show the error message .How to kepp my webform UI state still.

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<style type="text/css">
    #subfolder
    {
        width: 135px;
        height: 22px;
    }
    #txt_PRName
    {
        width: 127px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:FileUpload ID="selectxml" accept=".xml" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btn_show" runat="server" OnClick="btn_show_Click"        Text="Show" />
     <table id="container">
       <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" autopostback=fasle>

            </asp:Panel>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
              <asp:Button ID="btn_generatepdf1" runat="server" Text="Save" 
                Style="height: 26px"  autopostback=false onclick="btn_generatepdf1_Click"/>
                <br />
                     <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblerror" runat="server" BackColor="Red"     ></asp:Label>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is the Codebehind click event--

```
     protected void btn_generatepdf1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        try
        {
              string data = string.Empty;
            Dictionary<string, string> textboxValues = new         Dictionary<string, string>();
            StringBuilder labelnames = new StringBuilder();

            if (Request.Form.HasKeys())
            {
                int count = 0;
                Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(i => i.Contains("Txt_")).ToList    ().ForEach(i =>
                {
                    textboxValues.Add(string.Concat((i).Split('_')   [1].ToString()), Request.Form[i]);
                    labelnames.Append(i.Split('_')[2] + "    ".ToString());
                    count++;
                });
            }
            if (textboxValues.Any(i => string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Value.Trim    ())))
            {
                textboxValues.Where(i => string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Value.Trim    ())).ToList().ForEach(i =>
                {
                    lblerror.Text += string.Concat(i.Key.ToString()).ToUpper    () + "   ,   ";

                });
                lblerror.Text += "are Required";
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType (), "alert", "alert('" + lblerror.Text + "');", true);

            }
            else
            {
                createdirectories(textboxValues, labelnames);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblerror.Text = "Error :" + ex.Message;

        }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Add your code to this question

Comment: When working with dynamic controls you have to add them on every PostBack. ViewState will not keep track of these. So it may look like the  button click is hiding them, but it is not recreating them on that button click that is the issue.

Comment: how to stop postback,like validator controls function during page submit.

Comment: If you put validator controls on the page with the correct ValidationGroups it will stop postback if one or more is triggered.